# Como validar el mes siguiente por medio de la periodicidad?

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel

tengo 3 selects el primer select elijo la periodicidad que los traigo de una tabla pueden ser bimestral o semestral
el segundo select tengo los meses tambien traidos de una tabla y el tercer select igual contiene los meses pero solo es readonly entonces al momento de eleji una periodidicidad ejemplo bimestre y yo elija el mes de enero me debe llenar el campo mes con el mes que siga dependiendo de la periodicidad estoy trabajando con laravel  javascript y mysql

```
(document).ready(function () {
    let $body = $("body"),
        $periodicidad_id = $("#periodicidad_id"),
        $fecha = $("#fecha"),
        $mes_inicio = $('#mes_inicio'),
        $mes_fin = $('#mes_fin'),
        $descripcion = $("#descripcion");

        $fecha.datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: "yyyy",
        minViewMode: "years",
        startDate: "1972"
    })
    $periodicidad_id.on("change",function () {
        var periodo = $periodicidad_id.val();
        console.log($periodicidad_id.val());
        $.get('/catalogos/periodo-escolar/obtiene_periodo?periodo=' + periodo, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (value) {
            })
        });
    })
    $mes_inicio.on("change",function () {
        var mes = $mes_inicio.val();
        $.get('/catalogos/periodo-escolar/obtiene_mes?mes=' + mes, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (value) {
            })
        });
    })
       /* $mes_inicio.o
```

Answer (score 0):

En realidad sólo tienes que traer los valores posibles de la BBDD una sola vez, (así como los meses). Con eso defines dos variables en javascript que en mi ejemplo están definidas en duro.

El tercer select aunque sea readonly igual será pinchable, pero puedes usar CSS para darle `pointer-events: none`.

```js
var periodicidades = {
  'mensual': 1,
  'bimestral': 2,
  'trimestral': 3,
  'semestral': 6
};
var meses = ['Enero',
  'Febrero',
  'Marzo',
  'Abril',
  'Mayo',
  'Junio',
  'Julio',
  'Agosto',
  'Septiembre',
  'Octubre',
  'Noviembre',
  'Diciembre'
];

$(document).ready(function() {

  var $periodos = $('#periodos');
  var $meses = $('#meses');
  var $siguiente = $('#siguiente');

  Object.entries(periodicidades).forEach(function(periodicidad) {
    $periodos.append('<option value=' + periodicidad[1] + '>' + periodicidad[0] + '</option>');
  });
  meses.forEach(function(mes,index) {
    $meses.append('<option value=' + index + '>' + mes + '</option>');
    $siguiente.append('<option value=' + index + '>' + mes + '</option>');
  });

  function changeValores() {
    $mes = 1*$meses.val();
    $intervalo = 1 * $periodos.val();
    $siguiente.val(($mes + $intervalo) % 12);
  }
  $periodos.on('change', function() {
    changeValores();
  });
  $meses.on('change', function() {
    changeValores();
  });
  changeValores();


});
```

```css
#siguiente {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  Elija período:
  <select id="periodos"></select>
</div>
<div>
  Elija mes
  <select id="meses"></select>
</div>
<div>
  El mes siguiente es
  <select type="text" id="siguiente"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias  @amenadiel !!!